# unable to delete distribution repo in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

we are using Artifactory server and I encountered a problem today.

I tried deleting a distribution repo but I was unable.

I got an error message:

```
Deleting repo 'BASELINES-BINTRAY' failed: Could not merge and save new descriptor [org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration:
org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.distribution.rule.DistributionRule cannot be cast
to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)]
```

I looked at the logs of Artifactory and this is what I saw:

```
2018-02-13 22:25:16,525 [http-nio-8080-exec-2637] [ERROR] (o.a.u.r.s.a.c.r.DeleteRepositoryConfigService:66) - Deleting repo 'BASELINES-BINTRAY' failed: Could not merge and save new descriptor
 [org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration: 
org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.distribution.rule.DistributionRule cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not merge and save new descriptor [org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration: 
org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.distribution.rule.DistributionRule cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)]
```

any ideas what it means ?

Comment: Which version of Artifactory are you using? did you perform any upgrades recently? did you manipulate the config descriptor manually at any stage?

Comment: Hello , I use 5.8.3. for some reason it just solved on it's own

Comment: I'm having same issue.  No recent upgrade. Enterprise 6.10.3

Answer (score 0):

Here we have to do some steps to fix the issue
first login the existing machine
start and stop the machine

```
    sudo rm /opt/artifactory-oss-6.9.6/run/artifactory.pid
    
    bin]$ ./artifactory.sh start
```